# FxCop Report in Graph format in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, fxcop

Is there any way to show FxCop report in graph format in TeamCity like we can show in Jenkins using violation plugin?

Or is there any plugin in TeamCity that can convert FxCop output xml into a better formate?

I have tried FxCopReport.xsl in TeamCity. It is Ok but not as good as violations plugin in Jenkins.

So if anybody have any idea about it, help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FxCop runner](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/FxCop) in TeamCity or import FxCop results with TeamCity service message to make them displayed in dedicated TeamCity code inspections UI. This will also give you a statistical chart for the total numbers over time on Statistics tab of a build ocnfiguration.